# How do I capture an mpeg-dash stream using Python3 opencv?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0, mpeg-dash

I have a URL that links to an MPEG-DASH stream (https://something.com/manifest.mpd). I would like to capture this stream to work with the frames with OpenCV on Python3, which I have installed using pip3. How would I do this?
I have already tried `cv2.VideoCapture(URL)`, but this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [Vidgear](https://github.com/abhiTronix/vidgear). It supports mpeg dash format but it has yet to incorporate Apple HLS format. In case you want to work on a scalable solution, you can use amazon [AWS Media Convert](https://aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/), which can convert your source files to any format such as m3u8 or mpd. You can use AWS Media Live to do the same thing for live streams.